# forward declared class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a problem with C++.

I want to create two classes, A and B.

Class A has some methods that take an argument that is an instance of class B. But in Class B I also have some methods which take an argument that is an instance of class A.

I tried to forward declare class A and then define class B. Finally, I define class A.

Some code:

```
class A;

class B
{
  void Method1(A* instaceOfA)
 {
     instaceOfA->MethodX();
 }
  .......
};

class A
{
  Method1(B* instaceOfB);
  MethodX();
  .......
};
```

I code in Visual Studio 2010, and it shows an error because I invoke `MethodX` in class A but class A is not defined completely.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `I have a problem with C++.` What a great line to start with !!!

Comment: Just for your edifocatipn, the term is "forward declare," not "pre define."

Answer (score 4):

Put the definition of `B::Method1` after declaration of `class A`

```
//header file
class A;

class B
{
  void Method1(A* instaceOfA);
  .......
};

class A
{
  Method1(B* instaceOfB);
  MethodX();
  .......
};

// cpp file
 void B::Method1(A* instaceOfA);
 {
     instaceOfA->MethodX();
 }
```

This is the purpose of .cpp file. You declare the classes and methods in a header file then, add the definitions to the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving implementations of methods outside class declarations, like this:

```
class A;
class B {
public:
    void Method1(A* instanceOfA);
    ...
};

class A {
public:
    void Method1(B* instanceOfB);
    void MethodX();
    ...
};

void B::Method1(A* instanceOfA) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define and declare the classes the other way around?

```
class B;

class A
{
    Method1(B* instaceOfB);
    MethodX();
};

class B
{
    void Method1(A* instaceOfA)
    {
        instaceOfA->MethodX();
    }
};
```

Of course, this does not work if the `A::Method1` function also is inline.

Answer (score 0):

Is your impl code in the header file? If so, try moving it to a cpp file and #include A and B

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to implement class B inline? If you seperate the class definitions from the implentations (ideally putting them in .h and .cpp files), this problem will go away..

```
//blah.h

class A;

class B
{
  void Method1(A* instaceOfA);
  .......
};

class A
{
  Method1(B* instaceOfB);
  MethodX();
  .......
}l


//blah.cpp

#include "blah.h"

class B
{
  void Method1(A* instaceOfA)
 {
     instaceOfA->MethodX();
 }
  .......
};

class A
{
  Method1(B* instaceOfB)#
  {
      instaceOfB->Method1();
  }

  MethodX();
  .......
}
```